# How do I decode this response body?

Tags: json, http, dart, flutter, decode

I have this response body from a http push

> "{"identifier":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000"}"

I'd like to get the 000000... part as string

that's the relevant part of my code

.

```
.. async { 
    await http
          .post(Uri.encodeFull(mainURL + registrEndPoint + _stuff))
          .then((res) {
        if (res.statusCode == 202) {  
        Map _body = jsonDecode(res.body); 
                           // I checked debugging, the respons boy is ok
        String _id =_body['identifier'];
        return _id;
}...
```

I believe I'm missing something in the 'mapping'
and I suspect the combo 'quote-curlyBraces-quote' 
defeat my jsonDecode;

any suggestion?

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you get for `String _id =_body['identifier'];`?

Comment: appear to be null, when I debug it just skips the breakpoint

Comment: Shouldn't be hard to investigate using the debugger what's actually in `_body`.

Comment: 'hoovering' the mouse on it doesn't show anything,
next step is skipped and the return is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem adding this line

> String _body = res.body;

as described below,

```
await http
        .post(Uri.encodeFull(mainURL + registrEndPoint + _qr))
        .then((res) {
      if (res.statusCode == 202) {
        String _body = res.body;   //<--- HERE!
        Map _json = jsonDecode(_body);
        String _id = _json['identifier'];
        return _id ;
    });
```

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the [dart:convert](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html) documentation, you’ll see that jsonDecode() returns a 
`Map<String, dynamic>`, meaning that you do not know the types of the values until runtime.

```
Map<String, dynamic> body = jsonDecode(jsonString);
print('Howdy, ${body['identifier']}!');
```

Comment: thank for the answer, but it seems exactly what I'm already doing
[edit: i see the values returned in runtime while debugging,
res body value is the one quote in the initial post, but _id is null]